# How to store thread local data in PyQt?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

**What is the best way to store thread local data in a PyQt application?**

My application uses both `QThread`s and, through some dependencies, also native Python threads (from the `threading` module). My specific use case for thread local storage is mostly related to the former.

I can see some options.

1. Use `threading.local`. When called from a thread foreign to `threading`, `threading.current_thread()` returns a `_DummyThread` object. AFAICT, `threading.local` does support dummy threads, but it feels fragile. In particular, since a `DummyThread` [is never deleted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects), the store will not be cleared when the thread exits. Obviously I want no memory leaks.
2. When I know that the code in question will always run in a `QThread`, I could just store the data directly in the thread object obtained via [`QThread::getCurrentThread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#currentThread). No idea what would happen if called from a non-Qt thread.
3. Is there a [`QThreadStorage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadstorage.html) equivalent in PyQt? In Qt, it is a template, not a class, so I don't think it is available in PyQt.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have the feeling that the store is not correctly cleared when the thread exits"? Have you done any testing that provides actual evidence for this? If you have, it should be reported as a bug; if not, your "feelings" don't seem worth very much.

Comment: I apologize for the vague formulation. I have not tested it, but I have been looking at the Python implementation of `threading.local`. Per the documentation, a [`DummyThread` is never deleted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) (How could you? There is no reliable way to know when it terminated.) Consequently the data storage, once created by `threading.local` is never cleared.